# Math related game programming question

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to make a game engine in C++ using openGL and I've been stuck trying to create an importer for Collada Documents. My big issue is that the collada documents use math slightly more advanced than my personal knowledge, and so I was confused by the compression they use when saving polygons/polylists where they only give two of three coordinates for a surface normal and for one of two tangents on a given plane and the third must be calculated.

I was wondering if this question would be most appropriate on here or if it should go on the Math SE or if it should be on SO. The reason I assumed here is because it relates more to the collada compression methods than the programming or math itself, and I think that if someone happened to know this (perhaps game designers may have used .DAE files in their own projects) they may be able to explain it a bit better than I could as the question to programmers or mathematicians.

Comment: It's probably fine here.